# How to logout from yammer (oauth2 authenticated web app)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, logout, yammer

My web app is authenticated using yammer oauth2 authentication and i'm using bearer access token for further REST API calls,

I've to provide logout functionality but there is no API or other method to logout from yammer using oauth2 or any other method.

please suggest how can i provide logout functionality to my web app.

Also I tried to logout using calling url https://www.yammer.com/logout?from=nav by posting parameters "_method=delete&authenticity_token=" in application/x-www-form-urlencoded content.
but i'm getting 404 Not Found error.

is there any other way around?

Comment: Have you got a way to come out yet ? because i am facing the same one

Answer (score 0):

Make a `POST` request to `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/mobile_sessions/revoke` with the bearer access token as in other calls.

Comment: This doesn't fully logout from my yammer session, when i tried to login again, oauth api doesn't show me Login screen, instead it shows me App permission screen to Allow or Deny :(

Comment: have you got your solution ? if then please tell me how